# Creating a webpage with R and Github

Tags: r, pkgdown

I am following this [link](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/rmarkdown_websites_tutorial.html)
and at the very end I am getting this error

```
pkgdown::build_site()
```

> Error : Can't find DESCRIPTION
>   Error: Can't find DESCRIPTION

I would be appreciate any help.

Comment: According to **Hadley Wickham**, he responded to a similar issue by saying that "this is almost certainly the result of having an old version of pkgdown or pkgload; if you reinstall pkgdown the problem should go away."

Comment: I just install pkgdown like today,

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Github repository with us?